# How to write a correct addSbtPlugin call for NetBeans plugin for SBT 0.11?

Tags: scala, netbeans, sbt

I've added the folowing to `%APPDATA%\.sbt\plugins\build.sbt`

```
resolvers += ScalaToolsSnapshots

resolvers += "remeniuk repo" at "http://remeniuk.github.com/maven"

addSbtPlugin ("org.netbeans" % "sbt-netbeans-plugin" % "0.1.4")
```

This throws an exception as it can't be resolved.

I've noticed that the URL it tries is

```
http://remeniuk.github.com/maven/org/netbeans/sbt-netbeans-plugin_2.9.1_0.11.2/0.1.4/sbt-netbeans-plugin-0.1.4.pom
```

while the correct URL seems to be

```
http://remeniuk.github.com/maven/org/netbeans/sbt-netbeans-plugin_2.9.1/0.1.4/sbt-netbeans-plugin_2.9.1-0.1.4.pom
```

But SBT injects its version to where it shouldn't and doesn't inject Scala version to where it should.

What can be a correct addSbtPlugin argument then?

PS: I've also tried using http://vasilrem.com/maven instead of http://remeniuk.github.com/maven

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old but for others who have this problem try using

```
libraryDependencies += "org.netbeans" %% "sbt-netbeans-plugin" % "0.1.4"
```

instead of

```
addSbtPlugin ("org.netbeans" % "sbt-netbeans-plugin" % "0.1.4")
```

Comment: Would upvote all morning if I could, this helped me after hours of trying multiple different possibilities